# How to solve OSError for multiprocessing in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, sys, sanic

I have an application in the Sanic framework, so I used the multiprocessing module for upload file and send an immediate response to the client, so uploading the file can continue upload to the server. So this is working fine when the terminal is open, as i run an application in the background and close a terminal getting `OSError` in log.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py",
line 17, in __init__
sys.stdout.flush()
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Kindly [read stackoverflow's guiding](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to asking a good question to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: While I have no clear idea from your description, what you're trying to achieve and how and what's going wrong, I dare saying that for "upload file in background" the `multiprocessing` module is probably not the right choice. I cannot think of any task where it is the right choice in the context of a web application.

Comment: @Tim-Erwin i want just solve the error OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error for multiprocessing.

Comment: If you really want a (different) answer to your problem, I suggest you to give us some code. A working Sanic app is just 5 lines or so, just add the code that fails, which shouldn't be too much more, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that sanic is built around async, I would rather handle the file upload async, send a response and then await the file upload. I am guessing you are using multiprocessing to fork the process due to the request/response loop closing due to a response being sent.